# SQL query case when then in where clause

Tags: sql, where-clause, case-when

I read a lot of similar questions but didn't find a solution for me. Basically I would like to have a `where` clause (`AND PEKP.VORGANGS_ART = 'BE'`) only if a special condition (`PFSP.EINKAUFS_KZ = 2`) is true.

I tried in many ways like that:

```
SELECT *
FROM PFSP 
LEFT OUTER JOIN PFAK on PFSP.RUECKMELDE_NR = PFAK.RUECKMELDE_NR 
LEFT OUTER JOIN PEKP ON (PFSP.BESTELL_NR=PEKP.VORGANGS_NR) 
                     AND (PFSP.BESTELL_POS_NR=PEKP.VORGANGS_POS_NR) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN PMLB ON PFSP.KOMPONENTEN_ARTIKEL_NR=PMLB.ARTIKEL_NR 
WHERE PFAK.KD_VORGANGS_NR = '910-001213' 
  AND PFSP.RUECKMELDE_STATUS = '3' 
  AND PFSP.BESCHAFFUNGSKENNER = 'F' 
  AND CASE PFSP.EINKAUFS_KZ 
         WHEN 2 THEN PEKP.VORGANGS_ART = 'BE'
       END
```

but I keep getting errors:

> wrong syntax near '='"

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  Why are you using `LEFT JOIN`, when the `WHERE` clause is simply undoing them?

Comment: It's generally better to use `AND`/`OR` constructions instead of  `CASE` expressions in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Any null values involved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this CASE expression:

```
AND 1 = CASE  
  WHEN PFSP.EINKAUFS_KZ = 2 AND PEKP.VORGANGS_ART = 'BE' THEN 1 
  WHEN PFSP.EINKAUFS_KZ = 2 THEN 0
  ELSE 1
END
```

The order of the conditions is important.

Answer (score 1):

Skip the `CASE`, use `AND`/`OR` instead:

```
AND (PFSP.EINKAUFS_KZ <> 2 OR PEKP.VORGANGS_ART = 'BE')
```

If `PFSP.EINKAUFS_KZ` = 2, then `PEKP.VORGANGS_ART` must be equal to 'BE'.

If `PFSP.EINKAUFS_KZ` <> 2, it doesn't matter what `PEKP.VORGANGS_ART` is.

Comment: nice, shortest solution. but a little difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like:

```
AND (
      (PFSP.EINKAUFS_KZ = 2 AND PEKP.VORGANGS_ART='BE') 
      OR PFSP.EINKAUFS_KZ <> 2 --You may need to catch NULL as well
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM PFSP 
LEFT OUTER JOIN PFAK on PFSP.RUECKMELDE_NR = PFAK.RUECKMELDE_NR 
LEFT OUTER JOIN PEKP ON (PFSP.BESTELL_NR=PEKP.VORGANGS_NR) 
                     AND (PFSP.BESTELL_POS_NR=PEKP.VORGANGS_POS_NR) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN PMLB ON PFSP.KOMPONENTEN_ARTIKEL_NR=PMLB.ARTIKEL_NR 
WHERE PFAK.KD_VORGANGS_NR = '910-001213' 
  AND PFSP.RUECKMELDE_STATUS = '3' 
  AND PFSP.BESCHAFFUNGSKENNER = 'F' 
  AND ((PFSP.EINKAUFS_KZ = 2 AND PEKP.VORGANGS_ART = 'BE') OR (PFSP.EINKAUFS_KZ <> 2)   )
```